# Sinatra: how to store params hash in a session?

Tags: session, hash, sinatra

```
enable :sessions
post '/sending_out' do
    session[:data] = params.inspect
    params.inspect
end
```

`params.inspect` contains exactly the hash I want to pass in a session variable. If I copy it from the output on a page and paste in here `session[:data] = {hash-from-page}`, my further code works fine.

What's going on? Isn't params a simple hash?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are [disabled by default](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions). You need to enable them and then use the session hash from routes and views.

This means your code is correct you just forget to enable sessions so just add:

```
configure do
    enable :sessions
end
```

Comment: I did enable them, sorry for not mentioning!

Comment: oh then it's strange, and I strongly suspect that it's something else because I build a test project and it work just fine for me https://gist.github.com/fliiiix/7d67da8e01ac5303b71e